# Cannot search for a user by name

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, search

According to [the search FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search), to search for a user one uses the search parameters "user:<user>".  However, [searching for myself](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3AEther) actually yields a search result that appears to match all posts matching "user".  Am I indeed not worthy of "Super Ninja" status, or is this a bug? :)

EDIT: Now that this is answered, the question has morphed into a feature request.

EDIT2: I should have tried to use the "Users" tab, rather than just the search bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search users by their username: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users

Try typing in "Jonathan" and find me.

Comment: Try typing in "Eric" to find me on StackOverflow. I AM A GHOST.

Comment: you're my seventh favorite Eric, but with the right incentive, I might consider you for that sixth spot.

Answer (score 4):

You need to search by your user number, not your username:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:40468
```

If you look at the sample searches on the [search page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) you'll see that you need to provide it a user number, not a username.

Since usernames aren't unique, I don't think that it's a good idea to try to support searching by username as well, as you may get results from several users.

Comment: A ha, so simple! I totaly misunderstood the FAQ. But still, who is likely to remember a userid vs. a name?

Comment: You can also search by `user:me` if you're logged in.

Comment: @Ian: That's funny, mine works with `user:awesome`.

Answer (score 2):

Please reconsider.  If I type a username into the search box, it should match on user accounts first, and question content second.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to search for your own questions and answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me