# User search by real name

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-search

When [searching for users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users):

- "hayden", finds me (as it's my username).
- "andy hayden", does not (as it is not included in my username, but is as my real name in my profile).

Should this user search try to match real names as well as usernames by default?
Should there be an option to search users by their real name as well as by their usernames?

*I couldn't find this question asked before, maybe [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83426/extended-user-search), this question is about [filtering by username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14729/cannot-search-for-a-user-by-name).*
As a solution on SO, I changed my username to match my full name, as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40217/does-using-your-real-name-on-stack-overflow-help-with-your-career).

Comment: I have never noticed that problem. :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your real name is not shown in your public profile.

Allowing users to search for real name would be a violation of that policy.

Comment: I didn't realise that this information was not public. Thanks

Comment: Also, you can change your *display* name into anything you want, @hayden, which is what is searched when looking for users. (And [Make clear which profile data is visible to whom](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/make-clear-which-profile-data-is-visible-to-whom) might want your vote!)